# How do I correctly handle output directories for GCC test coverage profiling?

Tags: gcc, makefile, code-coverage, gcov, gcovr

I am trying to generate coverage data for my unit tests, with the ultimate goal of displaying said data as part of our automated build output.

We build using makefiles and `cs-make`, with `cxxtest` as the unit test framework. The autogenerated test runner file is C++, with all our application files in C.

The unit test target and recipe for a unit test executable is:

```
.SECONDEXPANSION:
UnitTest/%.exe: UnitTest/Tests/$$*/$$*Tests_cxx.cpp
    cs-rm *.gcda
    ..\cxxtest\bin\cxxtestgen --error-printer -o $@ $(addsuffix .h, $(basename $@))
    gcc -ftest-coverage -fprofile-arcs $(INCLUDES) $($*_SOURCES) -o $@
    ./$@
    gcovr -v
```

With `$(INCLUDES)` and `$(SOURCES)` as appropriate.

The recipe is executed by running (for example)

`cs-make cs-make -C TestPlatform -f UnitTest\makefile UnitTest\Test1.exe`

This builds `Test1.exe` and generates `.gcno` files. `Test1.exe` runs and generates `.gcda` files. `gcovr` correctly interprets these files and outputs coverage data.

So far, so good. But we are actually building and running several unit tests in parallel by executing:

`cs-make -C TestPlatform -j -f UnitTest\makefile UnitTest\all`

where `all` is dependent on all defined unit test executables.

To support parallel builds, I added this option to my GCC call:

```
-fprofile-dir=UnitTest/Tests/$*/Coverage
```

which puts the .gcda files for each executable in a seperate directoy.

But now, gcovr does not process the files correctly:

```
gcovr -v
Filters for --root: (1)
- <_sre.SRE_Pattern object at 0x0000000004FED600>
Filters for --filter: (1)
- DirectoryPrefixFilter(C\:\/Workspace\/CoverageTest\/TestPlatform\/)
Filters for --exclude: (0)
Filters for --gcov-filter: (1)
- AlwaysMatchFilter()
Filters for --gcov-exclude: (0)
Filters for --exclude-directories: (0)
Scanning directory . for gcda/gcno files...
Found 6 files (and will process 4)
Pool started with 1 threads
Processing file: C:\Workspace\CoverageTest\TestPlatform\UnitTest\Tests\Test1\Coverage\coverage.gcda
Running gcov: 'gcov C:\Workspace\CoverageTest\TestPlatform\UnitTest\Tests\Test1\Coverage\coverage.gcda --branch-counts --branch-probabilities --preserve-paths --object-directory C:\Workspace\CoverageTest\TestPlatform\UnitTest\Tests\Test1\Coverage' in 'c:\users\jfowkes\appdata\local\temp\tmpdfjja7'
Processing file: C:\Workspace\CoverageTest\TestPlatform\Test1Tests_cxx.gcda
Running gcov: 'gcov C:\Workspace\CoverageTest\TestPlatform\Test1Tests_cxx.gcda --branch-counts --branch-probabilities --preserve-paths --object-directory C:\Workspace\CoverageTest\TestPlatform' in 'c:\users\jfowkes\appdata\local\temp\tmpdfjja7'
Processing file: C:\Workspace\CoverageTest\TestPlatform\coverage.gcda
Running gcov: 'gcov C:\Workspace\CoverageTest\TestPlatform\coverage.gcda --branch-counts --branch-probabilities --preserve-paths --object-directory C:\Workspace\CoverageTest\TestPlatform' in 'c:\users\jfowkes\appdata\local\temp\tmpdfjja7'
Processing file: C:\Workspace\CoverageTest\TestPlatform\UnitTest\Tests\Test1\Coverage\Test1Tests_cxx.gcda
Running gcov: 'gcov C:\Workspace\CoverageTest\TestPlatform\UnitTest\Tests\Test1\Coverage\Test1Tests_cxx.gcda --branch-counts --branch-probabilities --preserve-paths --object-directory C:\Workspace\CoverageTest\TestPlatform\UnitTest\Tests\Test1\Coverage' in 'c:\users\jfowkes\appdata\local\temp\tmpdfjja7'
Gathered coveraged data for 0 files
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                           GCC Code Coverage Report
Directory: .
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
File                                       Lines    Exec  Cover   Missing
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
TOTAL                                          0       0    --%
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
cs-make: Leaving directory `C:/Workspace/CoverageTest/TestPlatform'
```

`gcovr` seems to be finding the files and handing them off to `gcov`, but no coverage data comes out.

I've tried various different `gcovr` options, but none seem to make this any better.

I'm running this build on Windows 10 in Eclipse CDT - this is requirement for us. I suspect based on other answers that there might be path and/or directory separator issues, but really I'm not sure of anything at the moment.

My question is: *what changes do I need to make to by makefile so I can add this coverage data to our build, which continuing to support parallel builds?*

I can of course restructure our unit testing to have a makefile-per-unit-test-suite, but this is substantial work and I would like to avoid it if at all possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is gcovr/gcov need to correlate the coverage data with source files in order to generate the coverage report, and the use of `-fprofile-dir` makes this difficult. AFAIK gcovr is not currently able to handle that case correctly. Gcovr's `--object-directory` option is unable to help in this case.

Consider to `cd` into a temp directory where you perform the build. So roughly, moving from

```
gcc --coverage test/source.c -o testfoo
./testfoo
gcovr
```

to

```
[[ -d build-foo ]] || mkdir build-foo
cd build-foo && gcc --coverage ../test/source.c -o testfoo
cd build-foo && ./testfoo
cd build-foo && gcovr -r ../test
```

Unfortunately, this would be a variation of your “Makefile per test suite” approach.

Another alternative might be to run tests in parallel in other directories, and then copy the coverage data one test suite at a time back into your build directory. This requires that you provide appropriate paths for the GCOV_PREFIX environment variable. This would be the same procedure as for using gcovr in a cross-compilation environment, as explained by gocarlos on the gcovr issue tracker: https://github.com/gcovr/gcovr/issues/259#issuecomment-406788661

Comment: Excellent answer, thank you. I think for our purposes splitting up the makefiles is the way forward.